What's the name of the 8th Century translation from Koine Greek into Latin of a criticism of dragon legends mentioning one disguised as a human?
When talking about dragon legends with someone, they mentioned an Eighth Century text that was a Roman, possibly they meant Latin, translation of Koine Greek, which mentioned accusations of people being actually dragons turned into people.

albeit it does [kind of] state that this stuff is nonsense [but...that] people did say and believe stuff like that. and that he himself did not believe the nonsense.

Does such a text exist? If it does, the title might mean something like "Regarding Dragons"?

Talking with someone is not a valid reference, the person might be misremembering

@MardukTrimegistus - Well, you can frame challenge me with an answer and say "This myth doesn't exist"...

Consider changing the wording of the question to "does such a text exist and if so, what is its name?" or something like that.

@Harel13 - Good tip! I'll take it!

On Dragons and Ghosts, by John of Damascus is one possibility.

@yannis - Looks good! https://dragondreaming.wordpress.com/on-dragons-and-ghosts/ - Asking my source now! Post as answer and I'll upvote at least!

The text you're referring to is On Dragons and Ghosts (Περί Δράκοντων και Φαντασμάτων), written by John of Damascus, an influential theologian of the early 8th century. This work, originally in Koine Greek, examines superstitions of the time, including claims that some people were actually dragons transformed into human form.
John critically evaluates these beliefs, dismissing them as myths while acknowledging their prevalence in some communities. His approach combines reason and faith, aiming to challenge irrational ideas through a Christian lens. This text offers a unique perspective on how folklore and theology intertwined during the Byzantine period.
